# UITableView checkmark accesory

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which i want to add checkmarks to selected cells or cells where `cell.textLabel.text` is contained in an array. If the array count is 0 the first cell should have a check mark (works but other cells are selected randomly) else add a check mark to cells where `textlabel.text` is contained array, also works but upon scroll random cells are selected. (I've added multiple selection to my UITableView). How can i fix this issue?

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel!.text = settings_categories[indexPath.row]
            if (userData[0].settings_categories.count == 0 && indexPath.row == 0){
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            }
            else{
                if (userData[0].settings_categories.contains(settings_categories[indexPath.row])){
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
                }
            }
            if (cell.selected){
                cell.selected = false
                if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None){
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
                }
            }
           return cell;
    }
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        NSLog("You selected cell number: \(indexPath.row)!")
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        if cell!.selected
        {
            cell!.selected = false
            if cell!.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            {
                //Add to array
                userData[0].settings_categories.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!)
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
                print(userData[0].settings_categories)
            }
            else
            {
                var counter = 0;
                for index in userData[0].settings_categories {
                    if index == cell?.textLabel?.text {
                        userData[0].settings_categories.removeAtIndex(counter)
                        print(userData[0].settings_categories)
                    }
                    counter++
                }
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should make sure that the accessory is set to none if it isn't set to a check mark, otherwise check marks will be left hen the cell is reused. Also look into using a NSMutableIndexSet to record checked rows rather than a string array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add one more thing  `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None` after cell initialised because in tableview its reuse privious cell so if cell has already checked(because it reuse the checked cell) then it by default come as checked so after update your code will be

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel!.text = settings_categories[indexPath.row]
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None// new added line
            if (userData[0].settings_categories.count == 0 && indexPath.row == 0){
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
               // cell.selected = true
            }
            else{
                if (userData[0].settings_categories.contains(settings_categories[indexPath.row])){
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
                 //   cell.selected = true
                }
            }
            if (cell.selected){
                cell.selected = false
                if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None){
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
                }
            }
           return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't store selected state inside the cell itself, since they are reused. You have to maintain separate array or indexset to maintain the selected indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Happened with me too. I, then, maintained an array to save selected indexPath.row & reloaded Table Data with that array such as rows which are saved in that array will have Checkmark Accessory after every scroll. This is just a work around and not the best fix.

Answer (score 0):

Set the accesory in the cell class implementation

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    self.accessoryType = selected ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```